# How to have background changed(border addition) when size becomes larger than 1024 pixels

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want to have a border along with the background in my website, when the screen size becomes larger than 1024 pixels.

I have used this in my code:

```
(max-width: 1024) { background-image: url("Gutter.png"), url(Background.png);
        background-position: left, center;
    }
```

But only the background appears even in screens larger than 1024 pixels.

Comment: I am unable to get the correct format which is required by me, I want the website to have a border on both sides(along with the background) when the screen width is greater than 1024 pixels. I am using twitter Bootstrap

Comment: What is the actual problem?  You don't know how to write media queries?  That you don't know how to set a background image?  You don't know how to apply borders?

Comment: I have applied the background, But I am unable to succeed in the border thingy, I have gutter.png file with me which is used as borders after 1024px but unable to get that issue solved?

Comment: The way the question is written (and tagged) implies that the problem is with the media query.  Without seeing the images, we can only guess how to code what you're looking for.  http://cssdeck.com/labs/rffj6nv6.  Have you looked at [border images](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/)?

Comment: I need the border to vanish when the screen size is equal to/smaller than 1024 pixels. But the background has to stay. The rest of the website is responsive just this issue is not clearing up?

Answer (score 2):

The proper format for a media query is like so:

```
@media all and (max-width:1024px) {
    #selector {
        background-image: ...;
        background-position: ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not able to get that?

Comment: Get what? Where are you putting this in your file? It shouldn't be inside the selector.

Comment: I was putting in the head tag under <style> can you point me where exactly i have to put it, I am using Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) { 

#elementID { 
  background-image: url("Gutter.png");
  background-position: left, center; }

}
```

Comment: I am unable to get the correct format which is required by me, I want the website to have a border on both sides(along with the background) when the screen width is greater than 1024 pixels

Answer (score 0):

Since your "border" isn't a true border, but a background image, you need to redefine your background within the media query (since you can't remove just one of the background images).

http://cssdeck.com/labs/kfoaijgc

```
.foo {
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/300/400) center center no-repeat;
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .foo {
      background:
          url(http://placekitten.com/300/400) center center no-repeat,
          url(http://placekitten.com/100/100) repeat-y, /* left "border" */
          url(http://placekitten.com/100/100) top right repeat-y; /* right "border" */
  }
}
```

If you were using a true border, then the solution would be simpler:

```
.foo {
    /* no border here */
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/300/400) center center no-repeat;
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .foo {
      border: 1px solid;
  }
}
```